# How to expess “nostalgia” in chinese？

Tags: grammar

So, I know that in general we can use something like 叙旧 to mean "reminisce (as if with old classmates). But how would we say something like "nostalgic" as in 
这首歌让我很Nostalgic。

怀旧？ 
舍不得？

THanks for any help given!

Comment: using nciku ＆ iciba：
（对往事的）怀恋、怀旧（情绪）、（homesickness）乡愁（病）、乡思 
nostalgia for sth。对某事物的怀恋
nostalgia industry 怀旧的行业
nostalgic 怀旧的； 乡愁的； 令人怀念的 to be nostalgic about/for sth  怀恋某事物
One of the actor's lines aroused his nostalgia.
电影主角的一句话引动了她的怀旧情绪。
She wallows in nostalgia for the past.她沉湎于对过去的怀恋.
He might be influenced by nostalgia for his happy youth 也许是对年轻时幸福时光的怀恋影响了他
Many people were nostalgic for the good old days. 很多人都很留恋过去的好时光
He made a nostalgic return visit to Germany 他满怀怀旧之情重访德国。

Answer (score 4):

If nostalgia means "longing for something past", the translation I can think of is:

> 这首歌勾起了我的怀旧情绪

Answer (score 2):

怀旧 and 怀念 are the best words for nostalgia in my opinion.

Answer (score 0):

Other than `怀旧` or  `舍不得` you can use `怀念` or `留念`

```
Example : 我很怀念这首歌
Example 2 : 这首歌很值得我留念
```

Comment: I don't think that's what @Stephen's phrase really means. The examples you gave mean "I am nostalgic of this song", whereas "这首歌让我很Nostalgic" really should be "这首歌令我缅怀过去".

Answer (score 0):

i remember 復古 and thinking of the word actually does give me a nostalgic feeling, so it totally works for me. a [quick check](https://www.google.de/search?q=%E5%BE%A9%E5%8F%A4&num=50&safe=off&client=firefox-a&hs=zh6&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&tbm=isch&tbo=u&source=univ&sa=X&ei=dro_VIvnDafY7Aacx4HoBg&ved=0CCIQsAQ&biw=1404&bih=650) shows that 復古 would appear to have rather vitage-ish connotations.

Comment: Not quite right, I think. 复古 isn't 怀旧, what's more, it can't be used (at least directly) to express one's feeling.